# How can I find examples of airports with specific approach types?

Tags: airport, approach, non-precision-approach, precision-approach

Can you guys help me find airports with these approaches:

1. An airport with only an LNAV mins (so no LNAV/VNAV or anything other than just LNAV)
2. One with an LPV lower than 200 feet
3. One with an ASR approach. And what is an ASR approach?

Comment: There are no LPVs with a DA lower than 200' AGL.  https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/techops/navservices/gnss/approaches

Answer (score 3):

All ASR and PAR approaches are listed in the current [Terminal Procedures Packet](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/).

They are not listed with the other approaches but in the front matter after the alternate airport section.  I have never seen a PAR approach not associated with a military airport.  There are joint use military/civilian airports that have PAR approaches and allow civilians to fly them.

[image: Albuquerque ASR Approach Minimums]
[image: Lemoore NAS ASR/PAR Radar Minimums]

Answer (score 1):

An ASR approach is an [Approach Surveillance Radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance_radar_approach) style approach. The guys on [MZeroA.com flew one in this video at KLAN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCzvEZOR7t0). They are not "at" any airport nor are there plates for them it is effectively a function of ATC. I have heard them flown at a few "smaller" class D facilities near me for practice. Generally to practice them you need to be somewhere that ATC does not mind clogging the radio up as they take a fair bit of radio work to fly.

[The RNAV (GPS) RW1 into KWWD has only LNAV minimums.](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2003/00476R1.PDF) (Note: It also has circling minimums which *most* LNAV airports will have unless terrain or some other issue forbids a circling maneuver).

As far as I know there are no LPV approaches that take you lower than 200 feet as [is regulated by the FAA:](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2090-107.pdf)

> Localizer Performance with Vertical Guidance (LPV). An RNAV function
>   requiring WAAS, using a final approach segment (FAS) data block, which
>   computes, displays and provides both horizontal and **approved vertical
>   approach navigation to minimums as low as 200 foot ceiling** and ½ mile
>   visibility.

Comment: Best bet for ASR approaches are current or former military fields, especially Navy fields. You can usually fly an approach to a USAF field if they're not super busy (not sure about Navy/USMC fields), and if you call ahead they'll tell you when they expect less busy times. They won't let you touch down usually, but you can fly the approach to a go-around

Comment: ASR approaches are in fact "at" airports, very much so, for two reasons: 1) the controllers need special training in order to do them and must maintain currency on the procedure, and 2) the approach path needs to be flight checked just as for any other approach. That is why specific minima are published for radar approaches to specific runways at specific airports.